# Is it possible to prove by induction that $1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n^2}<2\space\space \forall n\geqslant 1?$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logic, summation, induction

Let's denote the inequality in question by $A(n)$. I am looking for the way to prove this inequality using "direct induction" (see my question 1 below). By usual induction I mean $A(1)\&\left(\forall k\geqslant 2\space \left(A(k-1)\implies A(k)\right)\right)\implies\left(\forall n\geqslant1\space A(n)\right)$.

**My questions are**:

**1)** Is is possible to prove the statement $\forall n\geqslant 1\space A(n)$ by proving $A(n-1)\implies A(n)$ without using facts that imply $A(n)$? That is, by applying induction directly (it is allowed to use statements $C(n)$ that do not imply $A(n)$ and it is allowed to use induction hypothesis $A(n-1)$).
For instance using statement $\forall n\geqslant 1\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}\leqslant2-\frac{1}{n}$ is prohibited, because it implies that $A(n)$ is true and hence $A(n-1)\implies A(n)$ is true as well.
$ $

**2)** If it is not possible to prove $\forall n\geqslant 1 \space A(n)$ by direct induction, how one can *rigorously prove* this fact (the fact that it is impossible)? 
$ $

**3)** If it is possible to prove by direct induction $\forall n\geqslant 1 \space A(n)$ (can you show it?), are there examples of statements for which the proof by induction is impossible? Can you give an example?
$ $
$ $

**4)** Is  there some characterization of the set of statements $B(n)$ that possess the same or similar properties (something like *"proving $B(n-1)\implies B(n)$ is not possible although $B(n)$ is true"* or *"proving $B(n-1)\implies B(n)$ is not easier than proving $B(n)$"*). All statements of the "Inventor's paradox" type will fit, but probably there are some other examples.

Please note that I am not a specialist in mathematical logic, so the problem setup may lack rigor. But hopefully the idea is clear. If it is not, I am looking forward to suggestions on how to set the problem up in a meaningful way.

Comment: Here's an intuition-building (perhaps) remark. If the *only* thing you know about $1+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots+\frac1{8^2}$ is that it's less than $2$, then there's no particular reason to suspect that $1+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots+\frac1{8^2} + \frac1{9^2}$ must be less than $2$. Certainly there are plenty of numbers less than $2$ that become larger than $2$ once you add $\frac1{9^2}$. In this sense, it doesn't seem possible to prove your $A(n)$ directly by induction, without using additional information.

Comment: No you can't prove it directly. A value can be less than $2$ but greater than $2-\frac1{n^2}$

Comment: @jkabrg You did not give proof for you claim.

Comment: @marcin63, as the comments above clarify, direct induction alone is not enough. However, this does not rule out induction altogether. A common proof technique is to strengthen the theorem statement and then apply induction. This of course makes the conclusion stronger, but also gives a stronger induction hypothesis. I believe this may be what you do with $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}<2-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Please read the whole question once again. Your suggestion is mentioned there. I agree that Greg's comment clarify it, but in mathematics you don't just make sure that the theorem is clearly true, usually you prove it.

Comment: @marcin63, please see my answer which addresses your question. I admire the inquisitive meta-mathematical nature of the question, which obviously shows you have a keen mind and are a deep thinker. However, I will just comment and say that there are many parts to your question, which makes it cluttered and difficult to read. Ideally, there should just be one part to a question, and it should be well-formed and concise.

Comment: As $A(n)$ is in fact true, and all true statements imply each other, your condition (1) is very ambiguous. Literally anything you use to show $A(n)\implies A(n+1)$ arguably implies $A(n)$ by itself. As induction is central to the definition of naturals, the ambiguity seems more due to words like "direct" induction, which are ill defined.

Comment: @Macavity Can you show that it is ill defined? I am asking to prove the statement $A(n)$ using induction hypothesis $A(n-1)$ and other  statements $C(n)$ that do not imply $A(n)$.

Comment: $X \implies Y$ means if $X$ is True, then so is $Y$.  Any True statement $C(n)$ will imply $A(n)$, as the latter in fact is True.  So you are saying we should use only $A(n-1)$ and nothing else to show $A(n)$.  Do you see the problem?  Hence you end up making statements "not directly imply" etc., which are clearly subject to what you interpret as being direct, obvious etc.

Comment: @Macavity What happens if you do not know whether the statement $A(n)$  is true or not? So you can't use the fact that any true statement implies it? Does it change anything? What I have in mind is that the statement "$A(n)$ is true"  implies $A(n)$ and I wanted to prohibit using such statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to the parts of your question:

1. It is not possible to prove your statement by direct induction. I take this to mean the proof is *only* allowed use the induction hypothesis. Otherwise the question becomes incredibly vague.
2. The reason why is given in the comments. An inductive hypothesis of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}<2$ is too weak to imply $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k^2}<2$. The reason, as given in the comments, is that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k^2}<2$ could give you any number less than $2$, including all numbers $x$ with $2 - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < x < 2$. All such $x$ will violate the condition for $n+1$.
3. Not applicable.
4. This is a very broad question and it is quite ambiguous. It depends on what you mean by "easier". It also depends on what you mean by "proof".

Overall, I will just comment that the question you ask is very meta-mathematical. Such questions need to be very rigorously formulated or they don't really have any meaning. We can only talk *about* things like proofs if we start reasoning about them in a formal manner, and then we get into formal proof systems and all sorts of impossibility results like incompleteness theorems and undecidability.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Some questions. 1) I want to restrict the set of methods to those using induction hypothesis and not implying that $A(n)$ is true. Does this set coincide with the set of methods only using induction hypothesis? 2) Do you consider your proof rigorous enough? For me it sounds extremely convincing but I cannot determine whether it is indeed a proof. 4) This problem shows what I mean by 'easier' - I can prove this inequality using telescoping series in one line. I cannot come close to the proof via direct application of induction. So it's the common sense meaning.

Comment: I see that 'easier' is a vague term. What if instead I ask for statements that are impossible to prove by direct induction? By proof I mean the sequence of logical statements (that use conditions of the theorem and axioms) that imply that the original statement is true. Again not rigorous I guess, but it should be clear from common sense. Like we proved the statement if we showed that it is true in all possible cases. Also see the last paragraph of my question - probably you could give suggestions on how to formulate the question properly, since I feel you got what I had in mind.

Comment: @marcin63 First of all, yes, the proof is absolutely air-tight to me. There are two steps. 1) You prove a stronger condition by induction. 2) You show that the stronger condition indeed implies the weaker condition. As for the other questions you are asking, they are quite intelligent. The same sort of questions that were asked by mathematicians at the turn of the statement. However, you will need to make a decision, are you happy to stick with what you call "common sense" or do you want to delve into formal logic?

Comment: @marcin63 to continue, I am no expert in either (common sense or formal logic), but here is the conundrum. If you are saying things like "By proof I mean the sequence of logical statements (that use conditions of the theorem and axioms) that imply that the original statement is true"- you are really getting into the study of formal proof systems. But if you abandon this, and stick with "common sense", then the questions you are asking are not really mathematical e.g. how can we talk about "the set of methods only using induction hypothesis" without any definition of what a "method" is?

Comment: The point is, this is maths, so anything that is studied- including maths itself- must have a rigorous foundation: definitions etc. Without that, it is not really maths that is being done. Perhaps now is a good time for you to have a look at formal logic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic. It is interesting, even from a historical point of view. But personally I find it a bit cumbersome most of the time and prefer to work on maths at a creative/personal level.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: prove that $\frac{1}{k^2}\le \frac{1}{k(k-1)}$ for $k>1$

Comment: I'm pretty sure this violates the OP's conditions.

Comment: even i'm not sure

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Using your "hint" and telescoping argument immediately gives $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}\leqslant 2-\frac{1}{n}<2$. So it doesn't answer any of my questions.